# How to write a regex for a text including comma separated values in python?

Tags: python, regex, csv

I'm trying to write a regex in python to get F1 to F8 fields from a line that looks like this:

```
LineNumber(digits): F1, F2, F3, ..., F8;
```

`F1` to `F8` can have lowercase/uppercase letters and hyphens.

For example:

```
Header
Description
21: Yes, No, Yes, No, Ye-s, N-o, YES, NO;
Footer
```

What I've tried so far is 
`matched = re.match(r'\d+: ([a-zA-Z-]*, ){7}(.*);', line)` which matches the lines with the above format. However, when I call `matched.groups()` to print the matched fields, I only get `F7,` and `F8` while the expected output is a list containing `F1,` to `F7,` plus `F8`.

I have a few questions regarding this regex:

1. I guess `groups()` method returns the fields that were grouped in the regex using `(...)`. Why don't I get F1 to F6 in the output while they are grouped using `(...)` and have matched the regex?
2. What is a better regex I can write to exclude `,` from F1 to F7? (A short explanation of the suggested regex is much appreciated)

Comment: Why don't you just parse it as a csv?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham There are other lines in the document that don't match this pattern. Furthermore, the line numbers are printed at the beginning of each line. Would parsing as a CSV still work?

Comment: Add a proper sample and I can tell you.

Comment: Check for lines that don't match, and remove the line number with `line.split(': ')[1]`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I wrote an example in problem description.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That should work, but doesn't that require reading the matched lines twice?

Comment: Regarding the matched groups, it only preserves the latest matched and in this case the last matched is `F7`. You can try `((?:[a-zA-Z-]*, ){7})` in order to match all of them. And instead of `(.*)` you better to use a negated character class. `[^;]*`.

Comment: `list(reader([s.split(":", 1)[1]], skipinitialspace=1))`

Comment: @Kasramvd Thanks for your explanation. I couldn't get any of your suggestions work.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> pat = re.compile("""\s+ # one or more spaces
                      (.*?) # the shortest anything (capture)
                      \s*   # zero or more spaces
                      [;,]  # a semicolon or a colon
                     """,re.X)
>>> pat.findall("LineNumber(digits): F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8;")
['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5', 'F6', 'F7', 'F8']
```

Comment: Thanks Joran. This solution works well. Can you briefly explain how this works?

Comment: there you go :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only problem with this solution is that is matches some text in header that is comma separated but doesn't follow the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a construct like `(pattern){number}` then although it matches multiple instances, only the last one will be stored.  In other words, you get one bucket per `()`, even if you parse it multiple times, in which case the last instance is the one kept.  Note that you will get a bucket for ALL bracket pairs, even if they are not used, as in something like `(a(b)?c)?d` matching `d`.

If you know how many items to expect, then you can do your regexp the long way:

`\d+: *([a-zA-Z-]+) *, *([a-zA-Z-]+) *, *([a-zA-Z-]+) *, *([a-zA-Z-]+) *, *([a-zA-Z-]+) *, *([a-zA-Z-]+) *, *([a-zA-Z-]+) *, *([a-zA-Z-]+) *;`

This way, since you have 8 sets of brackets, you have 8 items in your `matched.groups()` array.  Also, we're not capturing the spaces and commas between the fields.

Given that your string is a CSV, you may be better off parsing it differently and splitting on commas rather than trying to have a single regexp to match the whole line.

Comment: Thanks Steve. There will always be 8 fields that I have to read. But, I was trying to avoid the solution that repeats the same pattern multiple times. 

Thanks for your thorough explanation.

Comment: why not just global it?

Comment: this is not an ideal regex ... I think you can do much better

Comment: I agree a better regexp is possible; I'm more addressing the explanation of why `(xx){7}` doesn't set 7 items, and how to exclude the commas.